# background operation in Jframe

Tags: java, swing

i have a jframe and jtextpane , i want to run a method that's checked ports in pc till the user close the jframe , i am trying by using windowlistner but the method run one time only and i want it to run till the user close the application

```
frame = new JFrame();

        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 552, 444);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowListener() {

            @Override
            public void windowOpened(WindowEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void windowIconified(WindowEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void windowActivated(WindowEvent arg0) {
                checkport(); // this run at first time only!

            }
        });
```

Comment: check out the [`Executors`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) framework..you'll want to make sure you execute `checkport` outside the Event Dispatch Thread, otherwise your UI will "freeze".

Comment: `frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);`-->Stop using that very bad habit. Where is the SwingWorker? What do you mean until the frame is closed? windowActivated is called when the frame becomes active (ie, when the user focuses your window).

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  2) Use upper case letters where appropriate (start of sentences, the word I, class names like `JFrame`).  Reading that is like trying to listen to someone who is mumbling.  I have better things to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Separate Thread for checking the port which is started while displaying the Frame. On windowClosing Event you stop the thread.

Sample Code:

```
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 552, 444);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    final CheckPort checkPort = new CheckPort();
    final Thread thread = new Thread( checkPort );
    thread.start();
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing( WindowEvent e ) {
            checkPort.stop();
            thread.interrupt();
        }
    });
```

Runnable for checking the port.

```
    public class CheckPort implements Runnable {
        private boolean checkPort = true;

        public void run() {
            while( checkPort ) {
                checkPort();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep( 100 );
                } catch( InterruptedException ex ) {
                }
            }
        }

        public void checkPort() {
            // do check port here
        }

        public void stop() {
            checkPort = false;
        }
    }
```